# Unable to update packages in KUbuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu

I made a fresh install of KUbuntu 18.04 and now when I try to update packages using `sudo apt-get update` I get the following error

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: It is not a fresh install ;-) You've added a PPA that is not good for 18.04.

Comment: Get rid of that ppa and install *latte-dock* instead. That's developed for Kubuntu (and other KDE distros).

Comment: Can you please post how to do that? @DKBose

Comment: Please read the comments to the answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file for removing the ppa. To install *latte-dock*, it's just `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt full-upgrade`, and `sudo apt install latte-dock` in that order.

Comment: ..dlfdskjbsdk,jsjb